# Is select function internaly call tcp connect?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, ace, select-function

Code Sinnpet:

```
int CreateaTCPSocket()
{
    int iSockID =  ACE_OS::socket(......);
    ACE_OS::set_flags(iSockID,O_NONBLOCK);
    ACE_OS::bind();
    if (ACE_OS::connect(iSockID ,....) < 0)
    {
        if (ACE_OS::select(.....,timeout) <= 0)
        {
            return INVALID_HANDLE;
        }
    }
    return iSockID;
}
```

My question is when connect is failed for non-block error and select is called and say select return success then again we need to call connect or select function internal do connect?

Comment: Please reformat your question such that the code is readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both blocking and non-blocking sockets you only need to call `connect()` once.

When the socket is non-blocking and `connect()` returns `EINPROGRESS` it needs to wait till the socket becomes ready for write using `select()`. When `select()` reports that socket is ready for write it can be either that `connect()` succeeded or failed.

To check whether a non-blocking `connect()` succeeded you can call `getsockopt(..., SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, ...)` that reports non-zero error on failure, or call `getpeername()` which only succeeds on a connected socket.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , your answer is, even if select reurn > zero also we need to check its realy connect or not right?

Comment: Right, `select()` does not report whether `connect()` has succeeded, only that its result is available. You can skip the check though and assume `connect()` has succeeded. In this case you will discover the error later on the first `send()` or `recv()`.

Answer (score 0):

why do call select once connect failed? What do you want to achieve with that?
select notifies the caller of any activity on the resources given as argument. These activities could be

- an error (example: tcp socket:  peer
  disconnected)
- data available (a blocking read can be performed without actually
  blocking)
- write possible (after last write failed with buffer full)

I guess in the scenario you described, select would always return EBADF (in some OSes i know) since the descriptor is not yet oopened or has already been closed.

hth

Mario

Comment: most of unix system have default timeout for tcp socket connect is 2 to 3 min , Now we need just 10 sec timeout so first we set socket to non-block and then call select with timeout if connect failed...